# Pdf structure without page tree

Tags: pdf

Good day!
I have pdf file with this Root node:

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 4 0 R
/Metadata 5 0 R
/Outlines 6 0 R
/PageMode /UseOutlines
/OpenAction [7 0 R /XYZ null null 1]
/PageLabels 8 0 R
/PageLayout /OneColumn
>> 
endobj
```

But, when i search page node (4 0 obj), I find nothing.
Please, help me, how can it be and when i can take the number of pages (only pdf format solution. not imagick and another)
Thank you

Comment: Can't be answered without seeing that file. Are you sure it is a valid file, i.e., can it be opened with a standard PDF reader?

Comment: I took several books in pdf format, and in one I found it.
Yes, i can open it.
This is link on pdf file
https://dropmefiles.com/cGdMw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find that object because it is stored inside a compressed stream, along with a number of other objects.

As always, you should start with reading the cross reference table `xref`. You will find this is also compressed; see **7.5.8 Cross-Reference Streams** in ISO PDF 32000-1:2008:

> **7.5.8.1 General**
>   Beginning with PDF 1.5, cross-reference information may be stored in a cross-reference stream instead of in a cross-reference table.

`startxref` points to a dictionary

```
6628 0 obj
<<
/W [1 4 1]
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 2 0 R
/Size 6629
/Type /XRef
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 3996
/DecodeParms <<
/Columns 6
/Predictor 12
>>
>>
stream
... (compressed data) ..
endstream
```

and decompressing this shows

```
index entry 0: 0 0 255
index entry 1: 2 3 0
index entry 2: 1 15 0
index entry 3: 1 3981 0
index entry 4: 2 3 1
index entry 5: 1 197 0
index entry 6: 2 3 2
index entry 7: 2 3 3
index entry 8: 2 3 4
index entry 9: 2 3 5
.. etc. ..
```

The first number in the entry is its status: `0` is "unused", equal to `f` in a regular xref table, `1` is equal to `n` in a regular table, and `2` means the object is compressed in yet another stream. See the ISO reference for the full meaning.

From this, you can see the `/Root` entry in object #2 is at offset 15 (decimal), and your `/Pages`, #4, is in a compressed stream at position #1. And indeed, decompressing this shows the expected

```
4 0 obj @ 3     % "Pages"
<<
  /Type     /Pages
  /Count    364
  /Kids     [ 
    9 0 R 10 0 R ]
>>
endobj
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!